# The Hessian from my optim() output in R contains mostly 0's. How can I interpret this?

Tags: r, optimization, hessian

The following is the Hessian matrix given to me from R's optim() function:

```
10230 0 0 0
0     0 0 0 
0     0 0 0
0     0 0 0
```

How can I interpret this? Is the first parameter that optim() optimized the only parameter that we can make uncertainty quantification on? Are the last 3 parameters' optimized values not credible?

*Update w/ More Background:* I am basically optimizing over parameters that are in a hierarchical model. Without getting too detailed, the first parameter is basically a nugget effect for a spatial covariance matrix and the last 3 parameters can be interpreted as regression coefficients in an exponential link function. I'm getting what appears to be correct estimates for all of the parameters; however, the Hessian looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: Very strange, can you tell us what options you ran optim with, and a little bit more about your problem?

Comment: @JohnMadden Definitely! The only options I used were "control = list(trace = 10), hessian = TRUE"; of course, I gave optim() my function with the parameters to optimize over, as well as "known" parameters. I added a bit more background in the post. Please let me know if there is anything specific that would help you help me! :)

Comment: Would you try adding "method='BFGS'" and see if that solve the issue?

Comment: @JohnMadden When I add that, I actually get the following error: Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Comment: Thanks for reporting that, is your nugget term parameterized in the log-scale, or not? In other words, is it possible that the optimizer is trying negative values, which is messing stuff up?

Comment: @JohnMadden Great question! It's on the log-scale

Comment: Word weird. Try using the hessian function from the numDeriv package, and see if it's any better: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numDeriv/numDeriv.pdf

Comment: @JohnMadden Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, my system is singular, which is an entirely new problem. Do you have any sources to recommend that I can study to truly understand all of this matrix stuff? I often find myself stuck with singular matrices and/or oddly shaped Hessians, and I would love to know how to fix these errors in the future. Truth be told, I have no idea how some of my derived matrices become singular, though I know what "singular" means.

Comment: Were you planning on using this Hessian to build asymptotic confidence intervals of your parameters, or something else? And does numDeriv give you the same matrix you've reported in the post, or a different one? Anyways, I learned linear algebra from Gil Strang, in particular from his youtube series on linear algebra and from his textbook.

Comment: @JohnMadden I was planning on using the Hessian to build the asymptotic confidence intervals. The hessian from numDeriv looks much better. No more 0s! Thank you for the recommendation on numDeriv and Gil Strang's lectures. I'll check those out. I appreciate all of your help :) If you put numDeriv as an answer, I'll mark that as accepted.

Comment: Cool, I'm not an asymptotics expert, but I think you can just punch through the noninvertability by taking the (negative) generalized inverse of the hessian (using for example MASS's ginv function) and look to the diagonal elements for marginal variances per usual.